# Calling getAuthToken inside a Teams Bot's Task Module

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a Teams Bot which can display a task module. This task module is a React app hosted in a separate Azure App Service in the same tenant and is accessible from a public endpoint. This React app is using the node package `@microsoft/teams-js`, and is calling `getAuthToken()` to try obtain a token from Teams for the user currently logged in.

The Bot's Teams manifest has been updated to include the following:

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "XXXXXX",
    "resource": "api://PUBLIC-ENDPOINT-URL-OF-REACT-APP/XXXXXX"
}
```

where `XXXXXX` is the Bot's app id. The Bot's Application ID URI for the Bot's App registration also matches the webApplicationInfo.resource value, as mentioned in the documentation for enabling SSO.

When I call `getAuthToken()` I am receiving the error: `Error: resourceDisabled`.

Does anyone know what is triggering this error? I have been engaging with Azure support technicians who have been unable to provide any help. Thanks

Comment: We have test the above scenario, it is working fine from our end.
Could you please check the configuration once. because this error happens when configuration is mismatch.
Reference link-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs